# Is there any way to drop request inside plugin

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor

Now I'm developing server application with ktor 2(2.0.0-eap-256).
What I want to do is, according to header or other information, Reject or set adequate http status to response and do not let request go into service logic.

Below is What I tried.

```
val testPlugin = createApplication("testPlugin") {
    onCall {
        if (call.request.headers["auth"] == null) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            return@onCall
        }
    }
}

fun Application.testRouting() {
    routing {
        get("/") { call.respond("hello") }
    }
}

fun Application.applyPlugin() {
    install(testPlugin)
}
```

But request goes into service logic defined by routing(with response which has HttpStatusCode.BadRequest). Is there any idea?

And also, I want to ask my understand about onCall/onCallReceive/onCallRespond is right

1. onCall is invoked first, when request come.
2. then, onCallReceive is invoked to handle request data such as file, body, etc
3. after all service logic, onCallRespond is invoked.

**Edit**

About the last question, it is solved. onCallReceive is called when I invoke call.receive() to get request content

**Edit**

Add routing code

**Edit**

So, I edit plugin like this.

```
val testPlugin = createApplication(
        name = "testPlugin",
        createConfiguration = { TestPluginConfig() }
) {
    pluginConfig.apply {
      pipeline!!.intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Plugins){
          if (call.request.headers["auth"] == null) {
              call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
              finish()
          }
      }
   }
}

data class TestPluginConfig(
    var pipeline: Application? = null // io.ktor.sever.Application
)

fun Application.testRouting() {
    routing {
        get("/") { call.respond("hello") }
    }
}

fun Application.applyPlugin() {
    val pipeline = this // io.ktor.sever.Application
    install(testPlugin) { pipeline = pipeline }
}
```

It works just as I wanted

very thanks to Aleksei Tirman

Comment: Could you please share a code of the service logic defined in routing?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I add testRouting() to sample. From other plugins that ktor supplies, there are "finish()" method to terminate call process logic. But I cant use this method in configuration of "createApplicationPlugin()"

Comment: The `finish()` method won't be present in the `createApplicationPlugin` API due to its complicated nature. You can still directly intercept pipelines to achieve the desired effect. In your example, the code in the route's handler doesn't get executed if the `auth` header is absent.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Very Appreciate! I add new code that works as I wanted, use pipeline and `finish()`

Answer (score 1):

According to Rustam Siniukov on the kotlin slack [here](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C0A974TJ9/p1652185509054159?thread_ts=1652184464.632849&cid=C0A974TJ9) it's enough to use `call.respond` in the plugin.
My tests confirmed this.